# Sound fail after Win 10 installation

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I replaced a harddisk from a Medion Akoya E6221. Because of the soon EOL from Windows 7 I choosed to install a fresh Windows 10.

If I take a look in the Device Manager, I see no issues or problems. But my main problem is, that I only can listen sound around 15 minutes after a fresh boot. After that I see only a pulse at the windows audio mixer, but I don't hear anything. If I switch from speaker to headset, the problem is the same.

I'm using the Microsoft Device driver. It's called HD Audio (Date: 2018-09-14, Version: 10.0.17763.1) Windows Update is finished.

I tried this [0], but I assume it never works on Windows 10.

Do you have any idea, what can be the problem and how can I solve it?

[0] https://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f23/after-2-minute-use-suddenly-no-sound-laptop-medion-akoya-796834.html#post5536065

Comment: So.. [this solution](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/Conexant-audio-driver-installs-and-works-then-randomly/td-p/6212193) (look for the GREEN cell) is for an HP but is the same problem that you are having.  Try what he did there.. you might need to go find some Conextant drivers.. but who knows?  They might already be on your system.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. My problem is, that the the driver is a Microsoft Driver (High Definition Device). The driver is up2date and I also can't do a rollback, so I can't pick another driver.

Comment: Sure you can! :)  You just need to be creative. Medion abandoned that laptop a while back but who says you can't get the same driver from HP, DELL, etc??  You might need a few stabs at it but try [this file](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp80001-80500/sp80327.exe) from [HP](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05519670).  Install drivers.. if it doesn't fix anything, right click HD audio and upgrade (let me pick option).. if that doesn't work, uninstall reboot.. play with it and you will figure it out.

Comment: I tried the HP driver, but I'm not able to choose this driver at the Windows Devices Manager. I also removed the driver, restarted and searched again for this specific driver. 
Which file from DELL should I test?
thank you for response.

Comment: For dell?? Try [this one](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=9vfxh).  All I can do from this side is guess..  Your Audio chipset has a specific PNP ID that needs to match the one in the driver file.

Comment: Hello @SeñorCMasMas I tried the Dell driver, but I can't pick it on the device manager. Where can I see the specific PNP ID?

Comment: Open Device Manager.   Right click on the driver "properties".  Details tab.  Property "Hardware Ids".  You might need to strip something from the front like "INTELAUDIO".. or whatever.. what you are looking for looks like this "FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0256&SUBSYS_10280828&REV_1000".  You will find the same string (or part of it) in the device drivers .inf file or windows won't allow you to install the driver.